# No sound in browsers on Ubuntu 20.04.3, but I have sound when I play games with wine

Tags: sound

My Ubuntu 20.04.3 does not output any sound when I am playing audio in the browser, via VLC or Rhythmbox. The only case where there is sound is when I am playing games with wine.

Any idea what can cause this issue?

Comment: some more information is required here, E.g. if you switch to "settings" and subsequently to "sound", is your sound card or motherboard sound module stated correctly there? What does it say? Also: try to use an Ubuntu friendly player like Audacious, that will make it easier to control your audio output.
Pulse Audio output works best in automatic bit rate depth.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Rob, I looked into settings, sound it shows perfectly the sound card. The drivers are in place, which is also why i guess wine works fine. Audacious didn't help too

Comment: OK, so you are still stuck. Can you see what kind of output is used? Like I said, Pulse works best in conjunction with automatic bit rate, but there are other options. Make sure that anything in Wine using sound is stopped, e.g. I have noticed that some applications stay on even when they do seem inactive. Make sure to close Wine completely.